# javascript - Scale canvas in all direction

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have two layers. One layer is big and another one is small. So to align the small layer with the big layer I am scaling the small layer to size of the big layer.

Scaling works on top/left but on bottom/right it's not working as I had hoped: it looks like it's not scaling equally in all directions.

I'm doing it like:

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var imageObject1=new Image();
    imageObject1.onload=function(){
       context1.clearRect(0,0,imageObject1.width,imageObject1.width);      
       context1.scale(1.0927,1.0956);
       context1.drawImage(imageObject1,0,0);
    }
    imageObject1.src=canvas.toDataURL();
```

JsFiddle of problem: https://jsfiddle.net/7cufxf6d/

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your offsets and ratio's seem wrong. In your code they are hardcoded and then shifted again using hardcoded values. You might want to re-investigate the values and how you obtain them.

Scaling (using canvas's transformation matrix) when using floating point values can introduce more rounding errors as opposed to using more fixed boundaries as provided by `drawImage`. As you are already hardcoding these values you might save some work (and memory) and both shift and scale the image when drawing it (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage):
`ctx.drawImage(image, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight)`

I slightly modified your fiddle:

```js
// Silver Layer
var canvas0 = document.getElementById("layer1");
var context0 = canvas0.getContext("2d");

var imageObject0 = new Image();
imageObject0.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
imageObject0.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('layer1').width = imageObject0.width;
  document.getElementById('layer1').height = imageObject0.height;
  context0.clearRect(0, 0, imageObject0.width, imageObject0.width);
  //    context.scale(1.5,1.5);
  context0.drawImage(imageObject0, 0, 0);

};
imageObject0.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/tIaNJku.png';
// Black Layer    
var canvas1 = document.getElementById("layer2");
var context1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");

var imageObject1 = new Image();
imageObject1.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
imageObject1.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('layer2').width = imageObject1.width;
  document.getElementById('layer2').height = imageObject1.height;
  context1.clearRect(0, 0, imageObject1.width, imageObject1.width);
  //context1.scale(1.0927,1.0956);
  context1.drawImage(imageObject1, -65, -10, 3020, 2680); // MODIFIED LINE

  //REMOVED SHIFT
};
imageObject1.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/29aRnzv.png'; //black
```

```html
<div style="position: relative;">
  <canvas id="layer1" width="100" height="100" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 0;"></canvas>
  <canvas id="layer2" width="100" height="100" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 1;"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: bravo can you tell me how you calculated these two values : 3020, 2680   , because context1.drawImage(imageObject1, 0, 0, 3020, 2680);    now creating black layer of same size to silver :)

Comment: Thx for the upvote, I'm now finally a 10K member. PARTY!!  To your question in comment: I first examined both images as 2 layers in photoshop to check if ratio was identical and overlay was possible with a single overall ratio (opposed to different y and x ratios). While doing so I got a pretty decent rough estimate for the values I used, and then I nudged them in trial-error kind of fashion in code. My point (after understanding your goal) was to show you a more direct approach. Now, you probably might want to automate this further.. (my comment continues below)

Comment: ... but you'd need to find some kind of known data regarding scale of your silk-screen and component layers. Then you'd have a fixed top/left coordinate for both images and you could calculate the scale. However, It might be a good idea to still provide some nudge (by 1 px) buttons for scale height, scale width, top and left ... At least until you are very confident in the auto-scale algorithm. WITHOUT known origin-points (so no regular data-image set) things WILL be a lot more complicated, perhaps you'd need to look into outline-finding routines and then scale according to these found sizes..

Comment: ya both layers are of 300 DPI  i used scale function to scale it and it worked but scaling is not on center so that was problem , ya i have calculated pixel data length of both layers for silver layer i have w = 2378;  h = 1955;   and for black layer  w = 2217;  h = 1873;

Comment: `ctx.drawImage` supports even more arguments (check linked docs and toy with them).. That way you can 'cut-out' a section of the source-image prior to drawing it scaled and shifted. That way might make calculating values simpler as you no longer also have to account for the 'blank' space around the actual image when scaling. In other words, if you see the raw image width and height as a container and the actual image (smaller) inside this container, you'd want to line up top/left coordinate of the actual image and calculate distance to bottom/right coordinate for both to find your values.

Comment: ya i have calculated distance for both layers from top to bottom , and from 0,0 silver layer have w = 2378; h = 1955; and for black layer w = 2217; h = 1873;